# foreach loop inside two other loops php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop within two other foreach loops. The third one should repeat only once, incrementing the value each time.
It contains the titles for 5 headers in an accordion:

```
$header_title = array(
'first_link_title',
'second_link_title',
'third_link_title',
'fourth_link_title',
'fifth_link_title',
 );
```

I've tried with

```
<?php foreach( $header_title as $value): ?>
<?php echo $value;?>     
<?php endforeach;?>
```

But the $value output on each header is

*first_link_titlesecond_link_titlethird_link_titlefourth_link_titlefifth_link_title*

The expected output should be

Header1   - first_link_title

Header2   - second_link_title

Header3   - third_link title

ecc...

The second loop displays the accordion itself and the first one has nothing to do with the accordion.

Ayy help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can post other loop codes too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prefix = 'Header';
$index = 1;
foreach ($header_title as $title) {
    echo $prefix . $index . ' - ' . $title . PHP_EOL;
    $index ++; 
}
```

Comment: After a slight modification of your code (Header1,2,3 ecc. was just for indicate the header div's in the accordion) the output is still * first_link_titlethird_link_titlethird_link_titlefourth_link_titlefifth_link_title*

Answer (score -1):

I think, this foreach loop must be outside two other foreach loops, not within. In other words those two other foreach loops must be within this "header_title" loop